# How to store object in state from Input Field?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch both the input value save it in the state but it does take only last the Input field value.

When in useEffect `console.log(state)` the object only stores and displays the last values `lname` I am not able to get why its not storing `fname`.

I want to store both the the value as object from input field.

```
const handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      ...rows[idx]
      [name]: value
    };
    setState({
      rows
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `...rows[idx]` in your handleChange

```
const handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...state.rows];
    rows[idx] = { ...rows[idx], [name]: value }; //here
    setState({
      rows
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `handleChange`, you overriding the changed state:

```
const handleChange = (idx) => (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  const rows = [...state.rows];
  // Add ...rows[idx] to keep the values updated from other names
  rows[idx] = { ...rows[idx], [name]: value };
  setState({ rows });
};
```

[image: Edit gallant-elgamal-5bq21]